# Google Sign in - already connected users

Tags: ios, google-signin

I have Google sign in in my iOS application and I notice that each time the user is trying to sign in via Google, Google SDK ask for the email and password and ignore (or not shared) already connected accounts.

How can I set any flag or request form Google SDK to use already connected accounts? Couldn't find that in "GoogleSignIn" iOS docs.

See image for the wanted behaviour:

[image]

Comment: You may  check `currentUser`  property https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in#ac49bf5dabe7b89781cd58e69cb015651

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, `currentUser` is `nil` and I have 3 connected accounts in the device